# select statement to get values between two strings in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table with two `VARCHAR2` columns:

```
trs_no trs_name
------ --------
JV1    ddd
 .      .
 .      .
 .      .
JV580  deee
```

I want to select for example all trs_no between `JV280` and `JV320`

I tried the normal between but didn't work because I found `JV29` in the results

So I tried also to get the length of the `JV280` and `JV320` in between it worked but it failed when the length is different.

How can I fix this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the `trs_no` into a two-character string prefix and the numeric postfix and compare them seperately:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  SUBSTR( trs_no, 1, 2 ) = 'JV'
AND    TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( trs_no, 3 ) ) BETWEEN 280 AND 320
```

If `trs_no` can have different sized string prefixes then you could use a regular expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR( trs_no, '^(\D+)(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) = 'JV'
AND    TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( trs_no, '^(\D+)(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) )
         BETWEEN 280 AND 320;
```

Comment: Is there any way more easier ?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanHesham You could add couple of virtual columns to the table and then just select from them in the form.